# Weird error with vectors in C++ when trying to push_back an instance

Tags: c++, vector, instance, push-back

I'm trying to do a `push_back` but Code::Blocks sends me a weird error. I have debugged this code many many times but I can't identify the error.
The method `LoadFromConsole` has the line with the error.

Specifically the error occurs when I go through the line `m_blocks.pushback(blocks)`.
 I will paste some of the classes. If you need more classes to help me, I will paste the rest of the code. Thank you.

```
class Block{
    int m_left;
    int m_top;
    int m_right;
    int m_bottom;


public:
Block();

    void set_values(int,int,int,int);

    void loadFromFile(ifstream*f);

      void loadFromConsole(int x,int y, int z, int w);

    int getValue(int side);


    void print();
};



void Block::set_values(int izq,int arriba,int der,int abajo){
    m_top = arriba;
    m_left = izq;
    m_bottom = abajo;
    m_right = der;
}




class Board{
        uint64_t m_timer;
        int m_step;


        int m_width;
        int m_height;


        vector<Block> m_blocks;


        bool solveState(State*state);
        bool isValid(State*state);
        bool isValidSide(State*state,int cell,int side,int cell1,int side1);
        bool isValidSideImplementation(State*state,int cell,int side,int cell1,int side1);


        void printState(State*state);
public:
        Board();


        void loadFromFile(ifstream*file);

        void loadFromConsole(int FIL, int COL);

        void solve();
};
void Board::loadFromConsole(int FIL,int COL ){
        m_height = FIL;
        m_width = COL;
    srand(time(0));

    matriz = new int*[COL];

    for (int i = 0; i < FIL; i++){
        matriz[i] = new int[COL];
    }
    matriz[0][0] = rand()%8+1;
    matriz[0][1] = rand()%8+1;
    matriz[0][2] = rand()%8+1;
    matriz[0][3] = rand()%8+1;

    for (int i = 1; i < m_width; i++){
        matriz[i][0] = rand()%8+1;
        matriz[i][1] =  matriz[i-1][2];
        matriz[i][2] = rand()%8+1;
        matriz[i][3] = rand()%8+1;
    }

    for (int j = 4; j < m_width*4; j+=4){
        matriz[0][j] = matriz[0][j-1];
        matriz[0][j+1] =  rand()%8+1;
        matriz[0][j+2] = rand()%8+1;
        matriz[0][j+3] = rand()%8+1;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < m_width; i++ ){
        for (int j = 4; j < (m_width*4); j+=4){
            matriz[i][j] = matriz[i][j-1];
            matriz[i][j+1] =  matriz[i-1][j+1];
            matriz[i][j+2] = rand()%8+1;
            matriz[i][j+3] = rand()%8+1;
        }
    }
        for(int i=0;i<m_height;i++){
                for(int j=0;j< (m_width*4);j+=4){
                         Block block;

                         block.print();
                         m_blocks.push_back(block);

                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Could you copy and paste the error?

Comment: Could you fix the code so it perhaps *compiles* ? Various missing identifiers, definitions, etc.

Comment: =========ERROR====================
 #0 77353541 ?? () (??:??)
 #1 773532FF ?? () (??:??)
 #2 773DCB60 ?? () (??:??)
 #3 773887B6 ?? () (??:??)
 #4 773532FF ?? () (??:??)
 #5 76AF9B9C msvcrt!malloc() (C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll:??)
 #6 00406244 __cxa_allocate_exception () (??:??)
 #7 76B97C64 msvcrt!_iob() (C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll:??)
 #8 00000024 ?? () (??:??)
 #9 00000001 ?? () (??:??)
 #10 00000024 ?? () (??:??)
 #11 00000064 ?? () (??:??)
 #12 0028FC1C ?? () (??:??)
 ====================;============

Comment: Okay, hold on a sceond while I edit the main post.

Comment: If you need help, please tell me.

Comment: @user2327884, please post code _here_ rather than on another site. It only takes that site disappearing, or your page on it disappearing, to make this question totally useless.

Comment: SO is not a message board. _This_ question is asked, answered and solved. Further problems should be asked in a _different_ question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're program has **undefined behavior**. You're both reading and overwriting memory you don't own. These two loop counters *far* exceed allowable indexing into the underlying memory allocation of all data rows:

```
// this is wrong. it will far-exceed the allocated
//  size of matrix[0], which is m_width int vals
for (int j = 4; j < m_width*4; j+=4){
    matriz[0][j] = matriz[0][j-1];
    matriz[0][j+1] =  rand()%8+1;
    matriz[0][j+2] = rand()%8+1;
    matriz[0][j+3] = rand()%8+1;
}
```

and later...

```
// Note:this is also wrong. it should be using m_height
for (int i = 1; i < m_width; i++ )
{
    // this is wrong. same problem as the other j-loop 
    for (int j = 4; j < (m_width*4); j+=4){
        matriz[i][j] = matriz[i][j-1];
        matriz[i][j+1] =  matriz[i-1][j+1];
        matriz[i][j+2] = rand()%8+1;
        matriz[i][j+3] = rand()%8+1;
    }
}
```

In both of the `j` loops you're enumerating in increments of 4, up to `(m_width-1)*4`. Suppose `COL` was passed in as `10`. The enumeration would be:

```
4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ALL OUTSIDE ALLOCATED RANGE
  ^^^ OUTSIDE ALLOCATED RANGE FOR [j+2] and [j+3]
```

Considering each row is allocated as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < FIL; i++)
    matriz[i] = new int[COL]; // << always smaller than 
                              //  4*(COL-1) unless COL is 1
```

Comment: @user2327884 helps or not, it *has* to be fixed no matter what.

Comment: Wow WhozCraig, that fixed the problem but now I have a new one. Would you like to check my update?

Comment: @user Then you should close and accept this question, and create another question, as its answer will not be relative to this (much). And regarding  your new problem, get a pencil and some paper and see if you can understand just how much memory your program requires. I'll give you a hint. After the *first* pass through solveState() 900-depth matrix (30x30) requires over 2.1gB.

Comment: Ok, I'll do it. Thank you WhozCraig. You're awesome.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265763/vector-error-terminate-called-after-throwing-an-instance-of-stdbad-alloc-wh

Answer (score 1):

With regards to:

```
matriz = new int*[COL];

for (int i = 0; i < FIL; i++){
    matriz[i] = new int[COL];
}
```

I think that first `new` be using `FIL` rather than `COL`.

Otherwise you're creating a `COL x COL` matrix rather than a `FIL x COL` one, and it's quite likely that you're therefore writing beyond the end of the matrix with your subsequent assignments, particularly if `COL` is less than `FIL`.

In addition, this code definitely writes beyond the bounds of the matrix, and appears to use `width` to boot, where it should use `height`:

```
for (int i = 1; i < m_width; i++ ){
    for (int j = 4; j < m_width*4; j+=4){
        matriz[i][j] = matriz[i][j-1];
```

The multiplication by four is unnecessary here and causes you to read/write indexes that are beyond the end of the array, hence invoking undefined behaviour. Specifically if, as you say, `FIL` and `COL` are the same value, the fact that you're accessing elements `m_width` and beyond is incorrect.

Comment: No, paxdiablo. In my code, the value of Fil will be always the same as COL, so it doesn't matters.

Comment: +1 I concur. especially if those are not equal (and we don't really know, but I'm guessing not).

Comment: I don't know :P just because a matrix has columns and rows. But don't deal with that

Comment: Please let me know if you need help.

Comment: It _does_ matter, a great deal. Regardless of whether it's a specific problem _now,_ it will cause problems later should your assumption become incorrect.

Comment: WhozCraig fixed the problem but now I have another problem.